# error in loading quicklisp.lisp

Tags: quicklisp

i run sbcl as follows:
* **(load "quicklisp.lisp")**

```
debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread #<THREAD
                                                   "initial thread" RUNNING
                                                   {AAE56C1}>:
  The variable “ is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV “ #<NULL-LEXENV>)
0]
```

it didn't show:
**"quicklisp quickstart loaded"**,why?how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typographical double-quote rather than an ASCII quotation mark. Did you copy and paste it from somewhere using pretty typography, like Word or a PDF or something? Does it make a difference if you type it directly into the repl?